# Capitalization of Hyphenated Words at the Beginning of Sentences

Tags: capitalization, hyphenation

Normally, when you start a sentence the first letter of the word is capitalized. What do you do with hyphenated words? Do the first letters of each hyphenated member get capitalized too? And then, by extension, what about brother-in-law?"

> Brothers-in-Law are usually married to one's sister.

or

> Brothers-in-law are usually married to one's sister.

(note the capitalization difference on "Law")

Comment: Just capitalize the first letter.